# Noise-canceling headphones with audio player

Tags: headphones

Are there any noise-canceling headphones with a builtin audio player?

Background: I am looking for noise-canceling headphones that would be convenient to use on long distance flights. So far all of the headphones I have seen required a separate device to use as audio player. I find that inconvenient because I need to carry an extra device and will need a wire between the two devices whenever using them. Moreover each seat usually only has a single outlet for charging.

Minimum requirements that I am looking for:

- Noise-canceling headphones with ear cups
- Builtin audio player that I can copy audio files to beforehand
- Must be possible to charge from a USB port

Nice to have:

- FLAC support
- Ability to disable data connections such that I can charge from an untrusted USB port.
- Option to use a cable for audio such that I can use the headphones with audio from inflight entertainment or a laptop.

Comment: Would Bluetooth headphones be what you are after?

Comment: @E.Nunn No. I will be using them in a setting were wireless communication is not allowed. I want them to play audio on their own without needing a separate device.